# Granting permission on a table, does as principal matter?

Tags: sql-server, security, database-schema

I am running a schema compare between two databases to make sure their schemas are identical.   On most of the tables, the only thing different is permission. 
Names changed to protect innocent databases.   "Otherone" is the sql login I am currently using, that has additional rights compared to most users.
Does AS [principal] part matter?
I tried to change it but got an error about rights.
I'm not new to sql but I am new to the security side of it.

For example
**Database A:**
GRANT INSERT ON OBJECT::[someschema].[sometable] TO [somerole] 
AS **DBO**

**Database B:**
GRANT INSERT ON OBJECT::[someschema].[sometable] TO [somerole] 
AS **OTHERONE**

Comment: Just ignore the AS clause and omit it when granting permissions. During schema compare and scripting, it shows the principal who granted the permissions. If you always execute DDL scripts as a dbo user, you won't see the noise.

Answer (score 0):

**AS**  Specifies a *principal* from which the principal executing this query derives its right to grant the permission.
The grantor (or the principal specified with the AS option) must have either the permission itself with GRANT OPTION, or a higher permission that implies the permission being granted.

If you are using the AS option, the following additional requirements apply:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I had already googled and saw that on the microsoft site, but it was not clear to me from what was there nor did it answer my question.